# AEM OSGi Configuration Multified Property with two or more fields

Tags: apache, osgi, aem, sling

Currently, we are able to use `@Property(unbounded=PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY)` to create a property in OSGi Configuration with Multiple-Values.

Is it possible to create a property in OSGi Configuration that behaves same as that of multifield functionality of AEM authoring dialogs? On click of Add button, the property field with all its-sub fields gets increased. So that we can add multiple entries of key/value pair.

```
[
    {
        "path":"/content/demo/page1",
        "date":"20-12-2018",
        "language":"english"
    },
        {
        "path":"/content/demo/page2",
        "date":"23-10-2019",
        "language":"french"
    }
]
```

The same key/value pair to be configured using OSGi Configuration and fetched as required.

Answer (score 3):

The felix console allows you to add multi-value properties. however,  they are typically a single field value. Meaning, you cannot create the complex data structure in your question. However, I have seen implementations that allowed you to enter an ordered CSV. For example, you could have a multivalued String OSGI property where each property is of the format:

```
<path>,<date>,<language>
```

your first entry then becomes:

```
/content/demo/page1,20-12-2018,english
```

Or, you could even enter the whole JSON as a string value, then parse it when you need it. But that becomes ugly to enter very quickly.

> You can use the above with any serializable data structure, but the more complex it gets, the harder it is to enter in a single input field.

Another option would be to create a page with a component that has a multifield and just point your OSGI config to the path of that page/component, then in your OSGI service, lookup that path and extract the configuration.

Comment: I think the CSV solution is the most versatile. Complex configurations could be deployed easily via content package and generated automatically. With some efforts a Maven plugin could be implemented to parse CSV files, create configuration files and everything could be updated and deployed in a CI chain, transparent for everyone involved.